# Associated Stirling Number of the Second Kind summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

A Norlund polynomial $B_n^{(z)}$ is defined by
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n^{(z)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^z$$ and the $B_n^{(z)}$ is called a Bernoulli number of order $z$.
We also have Stirling number of the second kind defined by the generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}$$
and there is a natural connection that allows the Stirling number $S(m+n,m)$ to be written in terms of the a Bernoulli number of order $-m$ since
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n^{(-m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)^m=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S(m+n,m)\frac{m!n!}{(m+n)!}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
From here, it is obvious that $$S(m+n,n)=\binom{m+n}{n}B_n^{(-m)}$$
Now, there is a generalization of the second summation above for associated Stirling numbers of the second kind which can be thought of like Stirling numbers of the second kind (SNSK) with a constraint.  So, for example a 1-associated SNSK, with notation $b(t;n,j)$ is the number of set partitions of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ consisting of exactly $j$ blocks, where each block contains at least $t+1$ elements.  In particular in reference to the generalization, we have
$$\sum_{n=tj}^\infty b(t;n,j)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\left(\frac{e^x-1-x-...-x^t}{t!}\right)^j}{j!}$$
For me, I am interested in the case where $t=1$ which gives me
$$\sum_{n=j}^\infty b(1;n,j)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^j}{j!}$$  I want my sum to start at $n=0$, so if I let $k=n-j=0$, then I get
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty b(1;k+j,j)\frac{x^{k+j}}{(k+j)!}=\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^j}{j!}$$
My issue here is that the polynomial's first term is $x^j$, not $x^0$.  If I want an analogous statement, should I be concerned with the starting point of my polynomial?  If then, for example I defined a similar "Norlund" polynomial where
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n^{(z)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{x^2}{2!(e^x-1-x)}\right)^z$$ and I wanted to find a similar relationship as above, I feel as though the index is where my main problem lies.  I can not in fact set them equal and find a relationship.  Any help?

EDIT:  I am feeling now as if, in the case of the reindexing, that it should be find to not even change the indexing, based upon the way these associated SNSK are defined, and therefore, the choice of starting at $n=0$ should be fine.  For example, if we expand,
$$\sum_{n=j}^\infty b(1;n,j)\frac{x^n}{n!}=b(1;j,j)\frac{x^j}{j!}+b(1;j+1,j)\frac{x^{j+1}}{(j+1)!}+...$$
Looking at the case where $n<j$, these numbers really aren't defined, and therefore we can treat them as zeros, right?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-3/branson.pdf) and [this](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-5/fielder.pdf) can help you. There are more results, just use google :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is concise and you're right. The numbers $b(1;n,j)$ with $n<j$ are zero.

But observe, that $e^x -1-x=\frac{x^2}{2}+\ldots$.

Therefore you can start effectively with $x^{2j}$ ($n=2j$)