# 1-Associated Stirling Number of the Second Kind identity verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series

I recently posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958022/associated-stirling-number-of-the-second-kind-summation?noredirect=1#comment1970243_958022) in regards to Associated Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind (SNSK) and I was trying to fix my equations to find and identity, and am now looking for verification that this identity is correct.

Let $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n^{(m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(x^2/2!)^{m/2}}{(e^x-1-x)^m}$$
I also have that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(1;n,j)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(e^x-1-x)^j}{j!}$$
Using these two identities, I came up with the following;
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n^{(-m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(e^x-1-x)^m}{(x^2/2!)^{m/2}}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt{2})^mm!}{x^{m}}\frac{(e^x-1-x)^m}{m!}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt{2})^mm!}{x^m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(1;m+n,m)\frac{x^{m+n}}{(m+n)!}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(1;m+n,m)\frac{(\sqrt{2})^mm!n!}{(m+n)!}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Therefore, I have that 
$$A_n^{(-m)}=(\sqrt{2})^m b(1;m+n,m)\frac{m!n!}{(m+n)!}$$
Rearranging, I have
$$b(1;m+n,n)=\binom{m+n}{m}\frac{A_n^{(-m)}}{(\sqrt{2})^m}$$
First, can anyone verify that this is correct?
Second, and I'd like to have this resolved...I really want to be able to define my original polynomial as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n^{(m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{x^2/2!}{e^x-1-x}\right)^m$$
However, my problem comes at the place where I get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n^{(-m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2/2!}\right)^m$$
$$=\frac{2^m(2m)!}{x^{2m}}\frac{(e^x-1-x)^m}{(2m)!}$$
Because I have that $(2m)!$ in the demonimator and the $x^{2m}$, there is no substituting the formula for the exponential expression.

I am thinking that if there is a connection, then my identity should be of the form:
$$A_n^{(-m)}=k^m b(1;2m+n,2m)\frac{(2m)!n!}{(2m+n)!}$$
where $k$ is an unknown constant or variable term.
Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Note:* The answer to your first question is affirmative: Yes, your calculations are correct.
>
> The answer to your second question is: Sorry, no *deep* insight from my side, but hopefully some helpful hints for further investigations.

A short look at your first part:

> **First part:**
>
> Since $A_n^{(m)}$ is used with a slightly different meaning in OPs first part and in OPs second part I will use here $\widetilde{A}_n^{(m)}$ and keep the original notation $A_n^{(m)}$ for the second part, which seems to be of more interest to the OP.

With respect to OPs [referenced question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958022) he introduced a *sort of generalisation* of [Norlund Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NorlundPolynomial.html), denoted $A_n^{(m)}$. A slight modification of these polynomials are $\widetilde{A}_n^{(m)}$ given via the following generating function:

> Let 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\widetilde{A}_n^{(m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{m}{2}}}{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Next, we look at certain [Associated Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $b(1;n,m)$ given via
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(1;n,m)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}{m!}$$
We observe, since
$$\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m=\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots\right)^m=2^{-m}x^{2m}\left(1+\frac{1}{12}x+\ldots\right)^m$$ 
the right hand side starts with $x^{2m}$ and so:

> The following is valid for the numbers $b(1;n,m)$
>   $$b(1;n,m)=0\qquad\qquad n<2m$$
>   and we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=2m}^{\infty}b(1;n,m)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}{m!}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We can now proceed with:

> **First part: Calculation**
>
> We use $-m$ in (1) and we observe:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\widetilde{A}_n^{(-m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}&=\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{m}{2}}}\\
> &=\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^mm!}{x^m}\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}{m!}\\
> &=\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^mm!}{x^m}\sum_{n=2m}^{\infty}b(1;n,m)\frac{x^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{by (2)}\\
> &=\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^mm!}{x^m}
> \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b(1;n+m,m)\frac{x^{n+m}}{(n+m)!}\qquad\qquad n\rightarrow n+m \\
> &=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^mm!\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b(1;n+m,m)\frac{x^{n}}{(n+m)!}\\
> &=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^m\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b(1;n+m,m)\binom{n+m}{n}^{-1}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
> \end{align*}

Comparison of coefficients gives:

> The following is valid:
>   \begin{align*}
> \widetilde{A}_n^{(-m)}&=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^mb(1;n+m,m)\binom{n+m}{n}^{-1}& n\geq m\tag{3}\\
> &=0& n < m
> \end{align*}

and we conclude with:

> **First Part: Result:**
>
> We see, that (3) coincides with the result of OPs first part and we therefore conclude that *OPs calculations are correct* (besides missing a range specification).
>
> We further see that $\widetilde{A}_n^{(-m)}=0$ if $n<m$.

---

Now, let's have a look at the second part. Here we use $A_n^{(m)}$ as it was given by the OP in the second part, namely

> Let
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n^{(m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^{m}}{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We can already start with:

> **Second part: Calculation**
>
> We use $-m$ in (4) and we observe:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n^{(-m)}\frac{x^n}{n!}&=\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^{m}}\\
> &=2^mm!x^{-2m}\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^m}{m!}\\
> &=2^mm!x^{-2m}\sum_{n=2m}^{\infty}b(1;n,m)\frac{x^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{by (2)}\\
> &=2^mm!\sum_{n=2m}^{\infty}b(1;n,m)\frac{x^{n-2m}}{n!}\\
> &=2^mm!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(1;2m+n,m)\frac{x^{n}}{(2m+n)!}\quad\qquad n\rightarrow 2m+n\tag{5} \\
> &=2^mm!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(1;2m+n,m)\frac{n!}{(2m+n)!}\frac{x^{n}}{n!} \\
> \end{align*}

Similarly to part 1 we compare the coefficients of corresponding powers of $x^n$ to get:

> \begin{align*}
> A_n^{(-m)}&=2^m\frac{m!n!}{(2m+n)!}b(1;2m+n,m)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\\
> &=\frac{2^mm!}{(2m)!}\binom{2m+n}{n}^{-1}b(1;2m+n,m)\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

Since 
$$(2m)!=(2m)!!(2m-1)!!=2^mm!(2m-1)!!$$
we observe:

> **Second part: Result**
>
> The following identity is valid:
>   \begin{align*}
> b(1;2m+n,m)=(2m-1)!!\binom{2m+n}{n}A_n^{(-m)}\qquad\qquad n \geq 0\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* It seems, that the difference of the result (7) to OPs suggestion $$k^mb(1;2m+n,2m)\binom{2m+n}{n}^{-1}$$ besides the factor $k^m$ is due to the fact, that the index shift of the sum in the RHS was $n \rightarrow n+2m$ instead of  $n \rightarrow n+m$ as it was used in the first part according to OPs calculation.

---

> **Hint:** I suppose that the paper [Explicit formulas for the Nörlund polynomials $B_n^{(x)}$ and $b_n^{(x)}$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122106001064) is helpful for further investigations. The polynomial $b(1;n,m)$ used here corresponds with $b(n,m)$ in the paper. Interesting formulas with $b(n,m)$ are stated in (1.14) and in the proof section.

Comment: That was so key, that analysis with the index really starting at $2m$...I'm already off and running.  THanks for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome! Good feeling to see the contribution is helpful! :-)

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Thanks a lot for the bounty! :-)